# Xcode 14 info.plist is not valid or not available

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I have upgraded Xcode to 14.0 Versions and. all. simulators to iOS 16. But non of the simulators are starting and when I try to build project it give me a lot of error say that info.plist is not valid or not available in your code for every dependency i have installed.
when I try to insall that application on real devices it working fine. here is my info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>XXXXX App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxnxnxnx</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) requires your permission to track in order to show you more relevant ads.</string>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713</string>

    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>2fnua5tdw4.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>ydx93a7ass.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>5a6flpkh64.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>p78axxw29g.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>v72qych5uu.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>c6k4g5qg8m.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>s39g8k73mm.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>3qy4746246.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>3sh42y64q3.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>f38h382jlk.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>hs6bdukanm.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>prcb7njmu6.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>v4nxqhlyqp.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>wzmmz9fp6w.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>yclnxrl5pm.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>t38b2kh725.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>7ug5zh24hu.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>9rd848q2bz.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>n6fk4nfna4.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>kbd757ywx3.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>9t245vhmpl.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>4468km3ulz.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>2u9pt9hc89.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>8s468mfl3y.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>av6w8kgt66.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>klf5c3l5u5.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>ppxm28t8ap.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>424m5254lk.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>uw77j35x4d.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>578prtvx9j.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>4dzt52r2t5.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>e5fvkxwrpn.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>8c4e2ghe7u.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>zq492l623r.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
      <string>3qcr597p9d.skadnetwork</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
    <key>GADNativeAdValidatorEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CallerApp want to access camera to upload a profile picture.</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>to show photos against numbers and to enhance app functionality  we do not share your contact with any third party.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CallerApp want to access camera to upload a profile picture</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CallerApp want to access camera to upload a profile picture</string>
    <key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-BlackItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-BoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ExtraBlack.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ExtraBlackItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ExtraLightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Italic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-LightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-MediumItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-SemiLight.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-SemiLightItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-Thin.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeo-ThinItalic.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-Black.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-ExtraBlack.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-ExtraBold.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-ExtraLight.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-SemiLight.ttf</string>
        <string>MarlinGeoSlant-Thin.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution was that I run the application from command line the this command `npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 14"` and its worked fine